# How to make Devise lockable with number of failed attempts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Using Devise 2.1.2 and Rails 3.2.6

I'm doing this Q&A just in case others run into this problem because I found little and scattered documentation for it.

This error may occur if you try to set up `Devise` as lockable.

```
undefined local variable or method `locked_at' for [someClass]
```

It means your model doesn't have the appropriate attributes.

Prerequisites:
Set up the following in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
# ==> Configuration for :lockable
# Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
# :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
# :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

# Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]

# Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
# :email = Sends an unlock link to the user email
# :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
# :both  = Enables both strategies
# :none  = No unlock strategy. You should handle unlocking by yourself.
config.unlock_strategy = :email

# Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
# is failed attempts.
config.maximum_attempts = 20

# Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
# config.unlock_in = 1.hour
```

Set up your model to include `devise :lockable`:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
```

Comment: I'm agreeing with "little" and "scattered" documentation....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Simply uncomment this strings in devise migration:

```
  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at
```

Comment: Also uncomment the add_index for :unlock_token at the bottom of the migration.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to successfully run this specific migration without removing my entire `User` table with the `rake:db migrate:redo VERSION=` command. Is there a better way? Or does one have to just write a brand new migration?

Answer (score 67):

`Devise` needs these three attributes on your model.  Therefore, generate the following migration and run it.

```
class AddLockableToExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :examples, :failed_attempts, :integer, default: 0
    add_column :examples, :unlock_token, :string # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
    add_column :examples, :locked_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Hope this saves someone else hours of google-fu.

Comment: You'll also want to add an index on the unlock_token if :email or :both.     add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true

Comment: Still not working for me. I set to `config.maximum_attempts = 3`, but after 4 failed times, and then typed the correct password, it still lets me log in.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to uncomment `# config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts` in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

Comment: don't forget to add :lockable to your model such as : 
 
 
`devise :confirmable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable`

Comment: In case someone wants to know more: [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-2.0-migration-schema-style)

Comment: updated devise wiki (July 30, 2016): [How to add lockable to users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:lockable-to-Users)