# Locking the user if he fails to answer the security field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am using Devise for my stuff.

In my scenario, if an user signs in, he will be redirected to a new page which contains a security question. If his answer matches, then he is redirected to the dashboard page.

Controller **sessions_controller.rb**:

> def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
>
> ```
>  home_security_path
> ```
>
> end

View **security.html.erb**:

> {:controller => "usersignup",
>   :action=>'check_answer'}, :multipart => false) do |f| %>
>
> ```
>                   <p><%= Question.find(3).question %></p>
>
>                   <p><%= f.text_field "answer_#{question.id}" %></p>
>
>                 </div>
> ```

If user fails three time to give the correct answer, his account has to be locked. How can this be done?

Comment: note your plan allows an attacker to maliciously lock someone else's account, if they can guess their username.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SecurityAnswers table, and in the check_answer handler create a new record for each answer. Store the source IP (despite hacking tools allow attackers to change that once per hit), the browser info (ibid), the user name, and whether the answer passed or failed.

Lock out the user after you can query that table via those details and find more than 2 failing answers within the past X minutes.

Comment: Generally, we will have failed-attempts in devise. like wise is there any possibility?

Comment: Here's an example using Devise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910176/how-to-make-devise-lockable-with-number-of-failed-attempts

Comment: Can you provide any url for your answer like storing the source IP, ibid

Comment: disregard checking the IP address & browser info. I was thinking of detecting crack attempts from multiple sources. The link I posted has everything you need.