# Devise don't redirect to recovery page after locked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Goal:**
Protecting the admin login.

**What I've done:**
With the help of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910176/how-to-make-devise-lockable-with-number-of-failed-attempts) I added a lockable account to my Admin Model.
And it's working like a charm and locks the user.
Admin Model:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :super_admin

  validates :password, :presence => true
  validates :password_confirmation, :presence => true

  has_paper_trail
```

**What I can't find:**
When I just try to login 3 times Devise just tries it, with the same login streak when I tries for the 4th time he shows the following:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

**What I want/need:**
I don't want Devise to show such a page, we don't want to let bots sniff the emails from the database.
So no redirect or mail must be send out after the x attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple answer [here](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable).

```
config.unlock_strategy = :none
```