# Rails 3.2.20 setting up Devise :lockable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a Rails 3.2.20 app which uses Devise 2.1.2.  Everything works fine, but Id like to add the `:lockable` feature to my project.  After 5 failed attempts lock the account for 2 hours.

I've been reading over the Devise documentation and various StackOverflow questions and answers but I have a different setup than some.

I handle sessions in my own controller and also use the strategy to login via email or username from the Devise WiKi.

Here is my current setup:

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => "my_sessions" }
```

**my_sesssions_controller.rb**

```
class MySessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_filter :check_concurrent_session

  def create
    super
    set_login_token
  end

  private
  def set_login_token
    token = Devise.friendly_token
    session[:token] = token
    current_user.login_token = token
    current_user.save(validate: false)
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
attr_accessor :login
    def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
            conditions = warden_conditions.dup
            if login = conditions.delete(:login)
              where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
            else
              where(conditions).first
            end
          end
```

**config/initializers/devise.rb (Excerpt)**

```
  config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :username ]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :username ]
```

So my question is, considering I handle sessions in my own controller and am also passing authentication via either email or username, how can I implement `:lockable` to lock out the account for 2 hours after 5 failed attempts?

I'm assuming there's a migration that I will need to generate and run, as well as setting the locking and unlocking strategy.

I read this post [How to make devise lockable with number of failed attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910176/how-to-make-devise-lockable-with-number-of-failed-attempts) but I'm a bit unsure of the unlock_keys and how that works.  Also in this post it talks about generating an index for the unlock_token, but I don't think I will need that since I'll be using a `:time` unlock_strategy.

Basically, I have Devise working well and I don't want to muddy the water or introduce any bugs into my project.

If anyone can help guide me through setting this up, I'd appreciate your assistance.  Sorry if the question is redundant or not clear.

Thanks in advance for your help.