# Unable to integrate lockable for number of failed attempts into Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, authentication, devise

I am new to rails+angular. For my app, I want to lock out user after 5 failed password attempts. I decided to follow this:
[How to make Devise lockable with number of failed attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910176/how-to-make-devise-lockable-with-number-of-failed-attempts)

But when I try logging in after 5 failed attempts, it lets me through

I added the :locked module to my user.rb (shown below) file so that the locked feature appears in devise.rb

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include TokenAuthenticatable

  TYPE = { 
    :admin => 1,
    :member => 2
  }  

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, 
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable,
         :timeoutable, :lockable ##this was added

  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

In my migrations then, I un-commented out the lockable part of it :

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :type

      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
       t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
       t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
       t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
      end
    end
```

To troubleshoot this, I also tried adding `:locked, :failed_attempts => 5`and uncommented out all the lockable features in initializer/devise. I am unsure on how to proceed - help would be appreciated.